# Spring error: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Let me start off by posting the [full stack trace](http://pastebin.com/Y7c6jXJa) .

Basicly, I have this DAO class:

```
package nl.alli.persistence.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * Created by thijm on 13-5-2016.
 */
@Component
public class Dao {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use spring in combination with hibernate 5 to autowire the SessionFactory.

My spring.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; Register Annotation-based Post Processing Beans &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<context:annotation-config />-->

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; Scan context package for any eligible annotation configured beans. &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="nl.alli" />-->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://url.url"/>
        <property name="password" value="tdjfkladsf"/>
        <property name="username" value="jaskdf"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" value="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>



    <!--<bean id="BjornJansonDataCollectorBean" class="nl.alli.pvoutput.BjornJansonDataCollector"/>-->
    <!--<bean id="PVOutputDataCollector" class="nl.alli.pvoutput.PVoutputDataCollector"/>-->
    <!--<bean id="PVOutputDataServiceImplBean" class="nl.alli.persistence.PVOutputDataServiceImpl"/>-->
    <!--<bean id="PVOutputDataDaoImplBean" class="nl.alli.persistence.PVOutputDataDaoImpl"/>-->
    <!--<bean id="DaoBean" class="nl.alli.persistence.util.Dao"/>-->
</beans>
```

Even IntelliJ sees the link between the `private SessionFactory sessionFactory` and the bean in `spring.xml`. I have no idea what is causing the exception, if anyone can help me out that'd be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably `spring.xml` is never picked up , so `mySessionFactory` has not been initialized , as suggested in the answers below. You could easily figure it out , if you open up the hibernate logs. At least , during start up it should print out the hibernate configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening basically due to the fact that Spring beans are not getting created from your Spring XML file meaning your **spring.xml** is not getting loaded in memory .

Here are some pointers to resolve your issue:

1. Check if you are loading spring.xml correctly from your web.xml
2. Ideally you should move all your beans from **spring.xml** file to **applicationContext.xml** file

Answer (score 1):

I see that you use spring-boot. As far as I know it didn't get xml configs by default.

Have you imported xml to java configuration somewhere in you code like this

```
@ImportResource("classpath:spring.xml")
```

Comment: Doing this gives me the following error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: Where is it located during build? What is in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing libraries on your classpath, if you are using Maven, add something like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```